# FirstOrDefault linq extension default item is null even though declaring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
ObjectSetting defaultSetting = new ObjectSetting();
defaultSetting.Value = "false";
defaultSetting.ObjectTypeSetting = db.ObjectSettings.First(ots => ots.Name == "PropName");

ObjectSetting testSetting = obj.ObjectSettings.DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSetting)
     .FirstOrDefault(os => os.ObjectTypeSetting.Name == "PropName");
```

My final implementation will differ slightly, but my issue is that testSetting should be a populated object of type ObjectSetting with a value of "false" if the result of the linq expressions is empty, the result I'm getting is testSetting is null.

I've checked S/O for similar cases, i've also checked the msdn documentation and I feel I'm implementing right but obviously I'm not.

Comment: For future questions, it would really help if you could provide a short but complete implementation - and using shorter names in your sample code would help with readability in the relatively narrow space available on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `FirstOrDefault` with a predicate - so if your `obj.ObjectSettings` is *not* empty, but none of the matched values have an `ObjectTypeSetting.Name` of `"PropName"`, you'll still end up with no results.

If you want to get your default setting in that case, you should use:

```
var testSetting = obj.ObjectSettings
                     .Where(os => os.ObjectTypeSetting.Name == "PropName")
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultSetting)
                     .First();
```

Comment: Alternatively you can do `.FirstOrDefault(os => os.ObjectTypeSetting.Name == "PropName") ?? defaultSetting`.

Comment: @Ryan: Yup, that's an option too.